# Create multiple tables at a time using the multiple folders in the s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was able to create the tables one after the another with the Infer schema in snowflake based on the parquet files in the s3 bucket.

For example, the files structure in S3 is:

```
s3://bucket/folder/subfolder/table1/TSfolder/FQfolder/part-1.parquet
s3://bucket/folder/subfolder/table2/TSfolder/FQfolder/part-1.parquet
s3://bucket/folder/subfolder/table3/TSfolder/FQfolder/part-1.parquet
s3://bucket/folder/subfolder/table4/TSfolder/FQfolder/part-1.parquet
```

I've created a stage (@estage) in snowflake till subfolder (s3://bucket/folder/subfolder/)
and created the file_format for 'Parquer_format'

and this is how I was able to create the tables individually

```
create or replace table table1
using template
(
select array_agg(object_construct(*))
from table
(
Infer_Schema
(Location => '@estage/table1'
,file_format => 'parquet_format'
,Ignore_case => True
)
)
);
```

Once the table is created, with 'Copy Into' command I'm loading the data.

with the above queries, created the Stored proc in snowsql language (with 1 variable in which I'll be passing the table_name) which will create and load the data at a time.

But, now I want to create all the tables at a time as there are 10000+ table present in the S3 bucket and doing it manually isn't possible.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: was that follow any logic in table name? like `table1`, `table2`, `table3` or it is random like `table1`, `tablex`, `table_abd`?

Comment: Just a random table names. 
Like: table1, tablex, table_abd, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach then,

1. Create a View that filter file paths

```
select distinct split_part(metadata$filename, '/', 0) as table_name from @stage
```

2. Create a Procedure, and start automation,

   1. Loop through the table_names from the view created in step 1.
   2. Generate SQL to create table.
   3. Execute created SQL
   4. Generate SQL for COPY command
   5. Execute COPY command

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried with ‘metadata$filename’ to get the ‘table name’ details 
    'SELECT DISTINCT METADATA$FILENAME FROM @estage (File_format => 'parquet_format') 
Output: ‘error parsing the parquet file: Invalid: Parquet file size is 0 bytes Rows 0 starts at line 0, column’ 
Post validating I found that in few tables there are empty parquet files so tried passing ‘on_error=‘skip_file’ &’continue’….but nothing is working out and unable to read/get the file names as there are empty parquet files present

Comment: I also tried with ‘list @estage’ which is providing the entire s3 URL s3://bucket/folder/subfolder/table1/TSfolder/FQfolder/part-1.parquet which is not required in my case…..just need a way to read all the table names

Comment: There are few things, You're not going to consume data, so technically, You don't need to setup `file_format => 'parquet_format` in select statement. which could remove file format related errors. If you willing to replace the or remove certain portion of list command output, you can do that by using `replace('s3://bucket/folder/sub_folder', '@estage')` will work.